# "Incorrect syntax near" with Ip address in query in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have tried create new view using an IP address in the query syntax. But this resulted in an error.

Query in View Editor:
[image]

```
SELECT *
FROM IP-ADDRESS.DATABASE.dbo.TABLE
```

Error:

[image]

In Normal Query (Work it):
[image]

How may I correctly execute this query?

Thank!

Comment: try putting brackets around it so   [IP-Address].Database.dbo.Table

Comment: sql editor erase it  "[]", remember this query is for a new view

Comment: post the entire error please, and the entire query since you said it's for a view. @Brad suggestion would fix the current issue.

Comment: *"sql editor erase it "[]", remember this query is for a new view"*? What? That statement makes no sense. @Brad is correct, the correct syntax is `...FROM [IP-ADDRESS].DATABASE.dbo.TABLE;`. The other solution, however, is don't use special characters in your object names. Change the object's name to `IPADDRESS` and you won't need to quote its name.

Comment: sql-server will never automatically change a statement or "sql editor erase it". Can you clarify what you mean? *EDIT* Like @Larnu said.

Comment: You error message isn't for the query above. You have a where clause you haven't posted... and who knows what else. Post the actual query...

Comment: creating a query with a same info is work. but i put the query in "New Views" and sql erase it []. i will put differences in the post

Comment: Try not using the UI and instead `CREATE VIEW`.

Comment: I love that you have blurred out or omittied the relevant parts for us to help you... it's like asking someone if they could proof read a document; however, only every 5th word **isn't** redacted.

Comment: @Larnu I'm sorry for not being clear in my explanation, next time I'll do better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using tsql instead of the UI. I tested in the UI and I see what you mean that it is not keeping brackets.

```
CREATE VIEW [YourViewName]
AS

SELECT 
  *
FROM [IP-ADDRESS].DATABASE.dbo.TABLE
WHERE Something
```